# python spark can not access http server in executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Python Spark, and I was trying to access http in each partition. But it always stuck there, the sample as following:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Fetch Http")
lines = sc.textFile("urls.txt", 10)
lines.map(fetch).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://node1/pages")

def fetch(url)
  http = urllib3.PoolManager()
  postResponse = http.request('POST',url,headers=JSON)
  jData = json.loads(postResponse.data)
  vectorStr = contertFun(jData)
  return vectorStr
```

Comment: Is server under your control? If not what makes you think it will respond  and not ignore requests as a potential attack?

Answer (score 1):

Some issues with your code:

- You don't provide timeouts so if connection just hangs it'll stuck
- You don't return anything so there is nothing to save
- You use connection pool where you cannot reuse it

Overall it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't past all of my code, actually I do have return a string I just edited my post. I used default timeout, by default it would be 60s.